# Disable all JPA Transactions in Spring Boot app

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions

I'd like to disable all JPA transactions in my Spring Boot services to increase performance. My app handles many database operations and to increase performance I'd like to use pgBouncer in my PostgreSQL database in state Statement pooling (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PgBouncer#Feature_matrix_for_pooling_modes)

Transactions make database operations very slow (probably???).

Is there any possibility to disable all JPA transactions?

My exemplary Repository:

```
public interface AgreementRepository extends JpaRepository<Agreement, Long> {

    List<Agreement> findByClientIdAndProductIdIn(Long clientId, List<Long> productIds);
}
```

My pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>26.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.starter.zipkin.sleuth}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.cloud.starter.zipkin.sleuth}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Maybe should I change default Isolation level to increase performance? My app handles so many databse operations that the whole process is very slow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You sure its because of transactions??

Comment: No, I'm not sure but I have to increase performance of my app... Someone told me that it can be a reason why my app is so slow with my thousands of database operations...  Any other suggestions how to speed up my app are welcome

Comment: *No, I'm not sure but I have to increase performance of my app.* So you are not sure, but you want to disable Tx because it fixes the issue for someone else in very different case. Bad approach IMHO.

Comment: I can hardly try to give you advice since there is no actual code that is "slow" in your post. I never speed up app by removing transactionals. Slow DB are usually due to bad db design, missing indexes and stuff like that - unless you got thousands modifications in single transaction than commiting indeed can be slow. But is that your case?

Comment: My service has many "Searchers" that execute multiple search operations on the big database and save results in another database (that is very small and fast). My problem maybe related to the multiple processes executed simultaneously. But ont he other hand when I run a single process, my "searcher" finds data in database too long. And I'd like to run for example 1000 processes simultaneously to find a lot of data and save it in another database, hence each second may change to days, months...to end up the whole process of finding data in my big database

Comment: *My service has many "Searchers" that execute multiple search operations on the big database and save results in another database (that is very small and fast)* well this sounds like missing indexes and badly written queries - transactions are not the culprit, nor disabling them will help you with that.

Comment: *And I'd like to run for example 1000 processes simultaneously* there is hardly a reason to do that. This would not give you improvement but degradation of performance (extra memory for thread allocation, switching between threads - all the overhead). CPU Threads count is reasonable number. That is how many things CPU can do at once. There is no magic in there.

Comment: If your queries returns like 10 results or less, try to run EXPLAIN directly on the database to see which indexes (or which are not) and try to add some indexes to improve performance. If you have dozens or houndreds of results - well that wont be fast. Select onlyt what you need, eg if you need only "name" of emptoyee, dont fetch whole employee - hydration and data IO takes a lot of time (relatively)

Comment: So as a recap:  what do you mean is that pgBouncer set in state Statement pooling
(most aggressive method. This is transaction pooling with a twist - multi-statement transactions are disallowed. This is meant to enforce "autocommit" mode on client, mostly targeted for PL/Proxy) with disabled auto transations for my Spring datasource is a bad solution? And I should find other solutions like @Transaction(readOnly=true) etc. ??? And why not to disable transactions? The problem is that I have really many connections to the postgresql as a Docker containers (managed by Swarm/Kubernetes)

Comment: What if I have really many single queries?

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a JpaRepository find methods are by default `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`

According to Vlad Mihalcea's blog, he is a Hibernate committer, this is already performance optimized:
https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-read-only-transaction-hibernate-optimization/

So I assume that your problem is not related to transactions.

Comment: Wow, thanks @Simon Martinelli for your answer. So you say that for all my Read Only  operations/entities should I use transactions with the flag readOnly = true?

Comment: Yes that's what JpaRepository is doing. The base implementation is SimpleJpaRepository. The code is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java